# Least Complex Method To Kill Python Script Running in The Background

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

I am running a script called mystepper.py in the background (/home/pi/mystepper.py); it moves two stepper motors for my RPi Camara. I would like to understand the easiest way to kill the mystepper.py script by name if possible. I then plan to create an alias in /home/pi/.bashrc so I can control the camera using my iPhone with the iFreeRDP app. The iFreeRDP app and similar apps have a broken key board such that the period and space bar don't work, thus the need for a shortcut alias to remove the need for spaces and periods.

After killing that script, I will make stepper motor position adjustments with /home/pi/moveit.py and then retart mystepper.py.

So if someone could show me the least complex method of killing a script, that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pkill` can kill a process by matching against its command line by using the `-f` flag. See the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill).

```
$ pkill -f mystepper.py
```

should do the trick.

**Updated to include Marks suggestion in the comment below**

To shorten this into a single command eg: `killit`, the following line should be placed into `~/.bashrc`

```
alias killit='sudo pkill -f /home/pi/mystepper.py'
```

**Note:** The above works without password auth on a Raspberry Pi because the default Raspbian `/etc/suoders` file disables password challenge when using `sudo` as the `pi` user.

i.e., in `/etc/suoders`

> pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

See [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) for syntax.

As a different user or in a situation where this does not apply, then adding the following via the `visudo` command at the very end of `/etc/sudoers` should work. Replace `pi` with the correct user that calls the script (replacing with `ALL` should allow all users to run mystepper.py with root privileges - have not tested this).

> pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /home/pi/mystepper.py

Comment: Yes, that works great! I would modify your answer just a touch. How I got it to work was: alias killit='sudo pkill -f /home/pi/mystepper.py That extra bit helps the newbies like myself but is just a given for you experts. Now I can just type killit to get the job done. Thanks!

Comment: No probs, have updated as you've suggested. Also included a reason as to why it works with `sudo` without a password challenge on Raspbian and how to achieve on other systems.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, I just noticed the alias command needs to have a closed quote. I think I missed that on my last reply. Should look like this with the ' at the end, right?  killit='sudo pkill -f /home/pi/mystepper.py'

Comment: yes, correct. Sorry, didn't see that either. Fixed.